# If a Congressional representative is arrested, does their seat become vacant?

Tags: united-states, law, congress

There is news about a congressman who is accused of certain very serious crimes.

However I have heard that it is legally possible for someone to run for congress from prison even if they are currently incarcerated.

If someone in the House is arrested in say the first half of 2022, would their seat be vacant until an election is held or would they be allowed to serve legally unless they're expelled?

Comment: Of course not, otherwise a zealous executive branch official (e.g. mayors, commissioners, governors, the president) could simply arrest congresspeople they disagree with, forcing them to be removed from Congress.

Comment: Note that accusation != arrest != conviction.  People are often falsely accused, for all sorts of reasons.  Even when they are arrested, charges are often dropped for lack of evidence.  If an arrested person is brought to trial, they may be found not guilty.  And even when they are found guilty, there are many instance where it is later shown to be a wrongful conviction.

Comment: On a related note, members of Congress are expressly immune from arrest per the U.S. Constitution during a session of Congress or while traveling to or from one, except for "treason, felony and breach of the peace" for precisely the reason Azor mentioned - to prevent bogus politically-motivated arrests designed to interfere with the ability of a member of Congress to perform their duties as such. This is in Article I, Section 6.

Comment: Also, there's a third option between "their seat remains vacant" and "they're allowed to serve." If a member of Congress is expelled, resigns, or dies during their term, the executive authority of their respective state has the power to appoint a replacement to serve the remainder of their term. A state or district doesn't lose its representation in Congress just because something happened to one of their members of Congress. This power is granted in Article I, Section 2 for the House and Article I, Section 3 (as amended by the 17th Amendment) for the Senate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They would be allowed to serve unless expelled. However, under House rules, once **indicted** for a crime for which a sentence of two years or longer may be imposed, a representative should resign from any committee or party caucus position they may hold, and **upon conviction**, refrain from voting until either the conviction is quashed or the representative is reelected. There are no automatic penalties for merely being **arrested**.

According to the CRS report [*Status of a Member of the House Who Has Been Indicted for or Convicted of a Felony*](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/RL33229.pdf), last updated in 2014, there are no penalties for a representative ***indicted*** for a felony, either under the Constitution, statutory law, or the Rules of the House. However, this is slightly out of date, as beginning in the 116th Congress, the rules package for the House of Representatives have changed to include provisions relating to members **indicted** for a felony, as well as **convicted**:

> 10. (a) A Member, Delegate, or Resident Commissioner who has been   convicted by a court of record for the commission  of a crime
>     for which a sentence of two or more years' imprisonment may
>     be  imposed  **should  refrain   from   participation in the
>     business of each committee of which such individual is a
>     member,**  and  a  Member  **should  refrain  from  voting  on  any
>     question  at  a  meeting  of  the  House  or  of  the  Committee  of
>     the  Whole   House   on   the   state   of   the   Union**,  unless  or
>     until  judicial  or  executive  proceedings  result  in
>     reinstatement  of  the  presumption  of  the  innocence  of  such
>     Member  or  until  the Member is reelected to the House after the date
>     of such conviction.
>
>     (b)  A  Member,  Delegate,  or  Resident
>     Commissioner  who  has  been  indicted   for   or   otherwise
>     formally   charged with criminal conduct in any Federal, State, or
>     local court punishable as a felony for which a sentence of  two  or
>     more  years’  imprisonment  may  be  imposed  **should  resign  from
>     any  standing,  select,  joint  or  ad  hoc  committee,   and   any
>     subcommittee   thereof,** on which such Member, Delegate,    or
>     Resident    Commissioner    serves,  and  **should  step  aside  from
>     any  party  caucus  or  conference  leadership  position**  such
>     Member,  Delegate,    or    Resident    Commissioner    holds, unless
>     or until judicial or executive  proceedings  result  in  acquittal
>     or  the  charges  are  dismissed  or  reduced  to  less  than  a
>     felony  as  described in this paragraph.
>
> [Rules of the House of Representatives - 117th Congress](https://rules.house.gov/sites/democrats.rules.house.gov/files/117-House-Rules-Clerk.pdf#page=44) - Rule XXIII

The report also notes, however, that "There is no express constitutional disability or “disqualification” from Congress for the conviction of a crime, other than under the Fourteenth Amendment for certain treasonous conduct". As a result, the only way in which a representative would be expelled for such an offence is as provided in the Constitution:

> Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings, punish its
> Members for disorderly Behaviour, and, with the Concurrence of two
> thirds, expel a Member.
>
> [US Consitution: Article 1, Section 5, Clause 2](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/article-1/section-5/clause-2/)

According to Chapter 12, § 13 of [Deschler's Precedents](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-HPREC-DESCHLERS-V3/pdf/GPO-HPREC-DESCHLERS-V3.pdf#page=171), however, this is unlikely to take place until a member's **conviction, including any appeals** - which would be long after the members' arrest.

> Where  a  Member  of  Congress has been convicted of a crime, neither
> the   House   nor   the   Senate will  normally  act  to  consider
> expulsion until the judicial processes have been exhausted.